# Pasting from a local clipboard to a Remote Desktop server (via C#)

Tags: c#, winapi

I have written a basic console function to paste files from the clipboard into a folder specified via the Command Line, which works fine locally (see below). However, I now need to get this to work on a Remote Desktop Server (RDP), pasting files from the local PC.

If I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, on the RDP - it will paste the files (so I know the permissions are ok). However, when I run my console app, it doesn't paste. I think my code is only looking at the RDP clipboard rather than the local one. I could really do with a pointer as to where to start (I'm pretty new to C#).

Here is what I have so far  I have also added the Windows.Forms reference:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TSPaste2
{
    class Program
    {
        //Getting destination foler
        String[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Setting Destination foler
            string DestFolder = args[0];

            if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
            {
                //copy to folder as set in the Command line
                foreach (string source in Clipboard.GetFileDropList())
                {
                    string Dest = DestFolder + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(source);
                    File.Copy(source, Dest);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clipboard is probably the wrong solution. What's the underlying problem?

Comment: I need to allow users to move/copy files from their local PC to a specified folder on the RDP server, so that our main application can process them.  I can't setup a shared folder as there will be multiple sites/users, and I don't want to open up an Explorer window, as they could move to other areas (the RDP security is slightly out of my control).

Comment: If the user has permissions to access the machine over RDP, then they can just start the remote desktop client and copy the files anywhere they like. So your idea that you will be able to have security is a mere illusion.

Comment: When the RDP loads, it is setup to run our application only.  They cannot open Explorer, TaskManager or anything (it's pretty much locked down).  When the application closes, they are signed off. However, to test things, I wrote a function within our app that opened up an Explorer window that test-users could use to paste files into, which works.  However, this would then mean that the Administrator has to setup permissions/folder access, which is something I really want to avoid asking them to do. A better way would be to run the above script/.exe, so that it just does it.

Comment: Why not just write a file receiver that sits on the server and listens on TCP for files. Or an IIS site. Or anything else. Really no reason to complicate this situation with RDP. Don't count on being able to do anything at all programatically to RDP because it does most stuff via system drivers.

Comment: Thank you Caesay - I'll take a look at those options now.

Comment: As I still haven't been able to find the way to do what I wanted (above), I have setup a local, shared folder for the RDP and using that instead.  I'm not sure how to close this question, so any help would be appreciated.  Thank you everyone for your help.